# Mobx installation in ReactNative fails

Tags: react-native, mobx

Mobx installation in ReactNative fails
I follow [this guide](https://www.badpenguin.org/learn-mobx-react-native-ten-minutes)

```
"react-native": "0.61.5"
```

I do the installs by creation but I get an error of

warn Package babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy \ package.json'

How do I install Mobx on ReactNative without these errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a [great link](https://jasonkang14.github.io/posts/reactnative/basic-setup) that helped me install Mobx in react native

```
npm install mobx mobx-react --save //to install mobx
```

> And then you have to install babel. The problem that I ran into while installing setting up this project was that I have to install

@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators

@babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy.

@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types.

```
npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types --save
```

And then you have to change **babel.config.js** like below;

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true}]
    ]
};
```

**Alternatively**, you can use mobx without designers and then all that is not needed

As shown in the [mobx documentation](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html)

Answer (score 1):

I love MobX (prefer it way more over Redux), Ive had to battle the whole gauntlet of Babel plugins to get decorators to work. Finally i decided to stop using them and just use the decorate method that comes with MobX.

[Great article here](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html)